# `docker-compose up` times out with UnixHTTPConnectionPool

Tags: go, docker, docker-compose

In our Jenkins agents we are running about several (around 20) tests whose setup involves running `docker-compose up` for a "big" number of services/containers (around 14).

From time to time, I'll get the following error:

```
ERROR: for testdb-data  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).
```

Haven't been able to reproduce this consistently. And I'm still trying to figure out whether or not there is a correlation with our agent's resources being at full use.

`docker -v` is `1.10.1` and `docker-compose -v` is `1.13.1`.

Any ideas about what this may be related to?

Comment: export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=<some_higher_value>

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Restarting docker service:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

and setting `DOCKER_CLIENT_TIMEOUT` and `COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT` environment variables:

```
export DOCKER_CLIENT_TIMEOUT=120
export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=120
```

are two workarounds for now.

Related issues are:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3927

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4486

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3834

Comment: One of those issues was open by me. In my case, it helped to increase the timeouts, and also to just not try to start too many containers at the same time in a machine that is not powerful enough for that.

Comment: increasing the timeouts did not helped in my case due to low spec of my machine. You're right. it seems to be machine resource limitation. But I couldn't find anything related to the amount of resources for each container!
Thanks @jleeothon for your comment.

Comment: Something else my team did was to make a script that starts a batch of containers, waited for them to be healthy, and then started another batch of containers, and so on. That way the computer was not overwhelmed by all the operations that ran during startup.

Comment: Well, i have 2 F series 64 core vms on Azure and i'm still facing the same issue on both of them. Increasing the timeout doesn't help. Restarting docker does.

Comment: Only a full reboot was helpful for me

Comment: For me, it seems to me that my docker network is not remove properly and have "crashed". The above recommendation did not work for me. So I took a slight modified approach: 
`sudo systemctl restart docker && sudo docker system prune -af`. The second command removes all resources on docker (including the network)

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. It was solved after change the max-file size value from a number to a string.

Wrong config

```yaml
logging:
 options:
       max-file: 10
       max-size: 10m
```

Correct config

```yaml
logging:
 options:
       max-file: "10"
       max-size: 10m
```

Comment: Converting the int to a string worked for me thanks, although those int value work fine in a stack deploy to a Swarm.

Answer (score 9):

```
docker-compose down
```

Running `docker-compose down` and then running `docker-compose up --build` may work. I am working on vscode and when I encountered a similar problem while building docker, this solution worked for me.

Before performing above mentioned command its better you refer to [what is the purpose of docker-compose down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/#:%7E:text=Stops%20containers%20and%20removes%20containers,defined%20in%20the%20Compose%20file)

Comment: This worked for me, but first I restarted the docker service `$ sudo systemctl restart docker`, just like @yash suggests. Then: `$ sudo docker-compose down` and finally `$ sudo docker-compose up -d`.

Answer (score 6):

```
docker-compose restart
```

Fixed my issue. This will restart all stopped and running services.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker-compose down
export DOCKER_CLIENT_TIMEOUT=120
export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=120

docker-compose up -d
```

following steps worked