# Can't run docker-compose up on client http request took too long to complete

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Hello I'm having a problem in my docker toolbox running in Windows 10 Home. When I try to run `docker-compose up -d` in my Docker the client takes too long to complete.

[image]

And when I tried to show the containers using `docker ps` the client is restarting.

[image]

What seems to be the problem in my end? I tried commenting the `tty: true` in the client in my docker-compose.yml. but it seems it doesn't fix it. Does anyone having the same problem? I'm using windows 10 home as my OS and I can only use docker toolbox.

Comment: Never post a screenshot of the error, if it's all text. It helps people to see it better and easier. While doing so use proper formatting for large code/output block by use of triple backticks.

Comment: Post output of command `docker logs` by passing the docker container as ID.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63521316/1883256) and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the Windows Subsystem for Linux enabled, and that you're using Windows Build version 18362 or higher. To enable WSL run this command in a PowerShell prompt with admin privileges:
`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`

Then you can continue from where you stopped.

Comment: Hi, you are answering a very old question. Is your answer directly handling the question? If this is just a suggestion or proposal to solve the proposal to solve the problem, then please move this answer to a comment on the post.